# Scope of static variable of member function

Tags: php, instance, scope, static-variables, member-functions

If I have a static variable declared within a (non-static) member function of a class, is it static to each instance of that class, or static across all instances?  Sorry if the answer should be obvious, I can't find it anywhere.

EDIT:

I have accepted zerkms's answer, but here is another example:

```
<?php

class X {
  public function fun($bar) {
    static $foo = null;
    if ($foo != null) print $foo . "<br/>";
    $foo = $bar;
  }
}

$x1 = new X();
$x1->fun(42);

$x2 = new X();
$x2->fun(123);
$x2->fun(666);

?>
```

Output:
42
123

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It would take a couple of minutes to check
2. It is shared across all instances

http://ideone.com/Cq2s6

Comment: After using PHP for over 10 years I am still learning things about the language.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  And on point 1, yes, I did test it right after I posted the question.  I don't regret asking it, because the answer will now be more available to others who need it.  I worded my title and tags carefully for searchability for that reason.  SO is reference material as much as Q&A...